# Magento debugging code

Tags: debugging, magento-1.7

I have developed some sites using cakePHP as a framework and loved the Debug and Exit code to stop everything from running so i could easily check variables being rendered.

Is there an equivalent in Magento that would let me stop everything after that point running and just render the page as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started to use the following code to some the immediate problems;

```
var_dump($var_of_interest); exit();
```